# how to get values that are in front of checked checkboxes and pass those values from HTML to Controller.js

Tags: html, angularjs, json

If you can give any suggestions for both HTML and JS. 
The HTML code for my application is given below:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat=" opt in bcfList track by $index" ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="bcfList[opt]" />
 {{ opt }}
 </li></ul>
```

The Controller.js for my application is given below:

```
$scope.bcfList=data.BCFNUMBER;
                $scope.getbcfnumber = function(index) {
                    $scope.bcflist=data.BCFNUMBER;
                    console.log($scope.selected);
                }
```

The BCFNUMBER is the key value of the list that am getting from backend controller.java using map functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add include the sample value of for `$scope.bcfList` Will be able to help better.

Updated code with the json values sent for `$scope.bcfList`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("myapp", []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        
        $scope.bcfList=  ["BCF-0025", "BCF-0049", "BCF-0051", "BCF-0091", "BCF-0096", "BCF-0100", "BCF-0115", "BCF-0117", "BCF-0118", "BCF-0130"];
        
        $scope.checkedbcfList = [];
        $scope.checkedBcf = function(item) {
          if($scope.bcfList[item]){
            $scope.checkedbcfList.push(item);
          }
          else{
            var index = $scope.checkedbcfList.indexOf(item);
            if (index !== -1) {
                $scope.checkedbcfList.splice(index, 1);
            }
          }
        }
        
        
        /*$scope.getbcfnumber = function() {
            $scope.checkedbcfList = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.bcfList, function (item, index) {
              if($scope.bcfList[item]){
                $scope.checkedbcfList.push(item);
              }
            });
        }*/

      }]);
    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in bcfList track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bcfList[opt]" ng-change="checkedBcf(opt)"/> {{ opt }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!--<input type="button" value="Get checked bcf" ng-click="getbcfnumber()"/> -->
  
  <div>checked BCF list: {{checkedbcfList}}</div>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Am getting an arrayList...not the key:value list like: data.BCFNUMBER
Array [ "BCF-0025", "BCF-0049", "BCF-0051", "BCF-0091", "BCF-0096", "BCF-0100", "BCF-0115", "BCF-0117", "BCF-0118", "BCF-0130", … ]

Comment: So I need to know how to get values of these numbers when checked

Comment: Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange

Comment: I think ng-model is missing in ur input tag. Please check that. If the input tag has both ng-model and ng-change this issue won't happen. it should be like **<input type="checkbox" ng-model="bcfList[opt]" ng-change="checkedBcf(opt)"/>** If that didnt work, please share the input tag